# Converting from a List to Hexadecimal in Python

Tags: list, python-2.7, hex, attributeerror

I have a list filled with hexadecimal values of a single byte.
If I do something like

```
list.encode('hex')
```

I get a good result. However if I ask for only part of the list to be shown

```
L=list[1:3]
L.encode('hex')
```

I get `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'encode'`

Why is this and how can I avoid the error?

Comment: Either one or both of your statements are false.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams could you please clarify what you mean?

Comment: The first piece of code will only give a good result if `list` is a string. If `list` is a string then the second piece of code will work.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams this is the same list though. It works in the first instance but not the second.

Comment: That does not make any sense. That's why I said what I did.

Comment: @micuzzo: if what you say is true (spoiler alert: it's not :-) then you should be able to create a complete self-contained example ([docs](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)) that other people can copy and paste.  If you try to do that, you'll probably find your mistake in the process.